# How to run a command as apache

Tags: sudo, apache-httpd, su

I want to edit my server files as a user in the apache group So, I need to `chmod` all files to 0775 as user `apache`. But, I am unable to `su apache`. I don't know the password for it, and entering empty password does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to edit my server files as a user in the apache group So, I need to chmod all files to 0775 as user apache

You do not need to `chmod` the files as user `apache`. Simply `chmod` them as root.

- Example: `sudo chmod 0775 file1 file2 file3 ...`

`chmod` -ing files as root does not change the owner.

Then as your normal user, who is a member of group `apache`, edit the files.

Answer (score 15):

To switch to apache user

```
su -s /bin/bash apache
```

Comment: changing all files to the apache owner is not exactly the best of the advices for security reasons. The owner user is also not the same across all distributions.

Comment: How has this been given 5 upvotes?! You still need the password to login this way, and as @RuiFRibeiro said, this is a security nightmare and would be even worse if the password wasn't required.

Comment: @Kenny83 You don't need a password if you perform the `su ...` above as root. So I'm upvote #7.

Comment: Answers the actual question, if not the OP's real problem, and is great for testing commands that have to be run as Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You run a script as the `apache` user if your user has `sudo` access:

```
sudo -u apache ./script
```

The `apache` user is usually set as a "nologin user" in `/etc/passwd`, which means you can't switch that user with a password.

[Credit](https://askubuntu.com/a/1309457/1067268)